# Error SQL syntax on FROM and JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone point me in the right direction why this sql query got an error?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40058/2

Expected results is to

get the names of Product on a table,

the count of sales on that product,

The amount (transactionamount)
and the net amount (statementdebit)

Comment: `transaction` is a keyword. you should change your table name

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40058/63

Comment: You missed one closing backet in sum statement and remove the spaces after functions like COUNT()  and SUM().

Comment: Add all relevant Informationen in SO. Not only in a link to sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things wrong in the query

- Closing parentheses missing on `SUM(transaction.transactionamount AS
  Amount`
- Extra spaces after aggregate functions on select e.g. `COUNT ()`

Here's the working SQL

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT transaction.transactionservicetype AS Product,
COUNT(transaction.transactionid) AS Count2,
SUM(transaction.transactionamount) AS Amount,
SUM(statement.statementdebit) AS NetCost
FROM transaction 
RIGHT JOIN statement ON transaction.transactionid = statement.transactionid
WHERE transaction.transactiondate = '2018-01-17' AND transaction.transactionservicetype = 'LBread';
```

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40058/26)

Answer (score 1):

a transaction is a keyword please cover it with **backtick** `transaction`

you are missing one parenthesis after **transaction.transactionamount**

another thing `COUNT ()`, `SUM ()` should be like `COUNT()`,`SUM()` no extra spaces required in function.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT `transaction`.transactionservicetype AS Product,
count(`transaction`.transactionid) AS Count,
sum(`transaction`.transactionamount) AS Amount,
sum(statement.statementdebit) AS NetCost
FROM `transaction` 
RIGHT JOIN statement ON `transaction`.transactionid = 
statement.transactionid
WHERE `transaction`.transactiondate = '2018-01-17' AND 
`transaction`.transactionservicetype = 'LBread';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Missing Closing parentheses on "SUM(transaction.transactionamount AS Amount" and 
Extra Spaces between COUNT(),SUM() function like "SUM (transaction.transactionamount):

Updated query as per  below using left outer join and 
SQL-Fiddle is "http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40058/92" : 

SELECT 
T.transactionservicetype AS Product,
COUNT(T.transactionid) AS CountTotal,
SUM(T.transactionamount) AS Amount,
SUM(S.statementdebit) AS NetCost 
FROM statement S  
left outer join transaction T  ON T.transactionid = S.transactionid
WHERE T.transactiondate = '2018-01-17' AND T.transactionservicetype = 'LBread'
group by T.transactionservicetype;
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you, i'm bit confuse because your table naming field naming.

this my solution
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40058/83/0

sql query :

```
    SELECT sum(a.statementdebit) debit,count(a.statementdesc) tot_prod,
sum(b.transactionamount) amount,a.statementdesc
FROM 
statement a
JOIN transaction b on a.transactionid=b.transactionid
where b.transactiondate = '2018-01-17'
group by a.statementdesc
```